# Pretraining Deep Learning Model for Weight Initialization

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

When pretraining Deep Learning model (lets say a deep convolutional neural netowork) in order to achieve good weight initialization, do I use entire training set without validation (so that I avoid information leak) or just subset of training set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fine-tune your network after training it on your dataset then you can use the same dataset (making sure that the data in the training/test, and validation sets do not switch around). What you can also do as 'pre-training' is to download a model that is already trained on a similar dataset/problem to yours and then training it on your dataset. This is known as transfer learning and works well for similar problems, but of course the bigger the gap between the 2 problems the more you need to train.

In conclusion: you can use any dataset as long as the validation set remains hidden from the network.

Answer (score 1):

I think if we divide the dataset into training, validation and test data, it will be more useful. Keeping a completely new test data aside and validating the model with only validation data is a good choice. Entire training data should be used for training.